# C# COM interface not visible when genericity is involved

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, com

I work on a professional project with a lot of COM involved, and we encounter the following issue:

With this code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IComFakeCall { }

[ComVisible(false)]
public class BaseClass<T> { }

[ComVisible(true)]
public class ComFakeCall : BaseClass<string>, IComFakeCall { }
```

the interface `IComFakeCall` is not visible from the Excel VBA editor.

Whereas it is visible if I remove the genericity, like that :

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IComFakeCall { }

[ComVisible(false)]
public class BaseClass { }

[ComVisible(true)]
public class ComFakeCall : BaseClass, IComFakeCall { }
```

How come my interface from the first example isn't visible?

Is there a known issue with COM objects and the inheritance of generic classes?

Comment: COM does not support generics whatsoever.  The problem is that you expose too much of the class, unnecessary since you appear to already have a good choice for the default interface.  IComFakeCall should get the job done, hopefully it isn't really fake.  Simply fix by applying.    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] to the class so no generic members need to be exposed at all.

Comment: Hello, I don't think I get your comment: I don't have any issue with `ComFakeCall`, it's the interface `IComFakeCall` that is not visible in my IDE. I tried `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I can't see what you see, making everything fake doesn't exactly help me help you.  VBA does not support interfaces at all so hard to guess what you could be looking at.  You should see the methods that you added to the IComFakeCall interface.  And none of the methods in BaseClass and System.Object.

Comment: Well, I don't have any issue with the methods (I removed them to make a concise example), it's the interface `IComFakeCall` itself that I can't see. What I mean by that is that in the Excel vba editor, under View\Object Browser, if I explore the objects of my library I can see the interface`IComFakeCall` without any issue in the second case (when no genericity is involved), but not in the first.